# With ubuntu 22,localhost/phpmyadmin is occuring "localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

When I call localhost, nginx work well.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkJ8p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjVzq.png)
When I call localhost/info.php, it also work well.

console error
`FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'static' (T_STATIC) in /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php on line 272" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"`

Comment: Ubuntu 22?  So you're asking about a Ubuntu Core 22 system? and not 22.04 ?  Please clarify as the *year* products have some differences to the more widely used *year.month* systems.

Comment: I have this issue too.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is there with Ubuntu 22 system which has php version 7.4 running. I had the same issue in my ubuntu 22 + php 7.4-fpm system.  Phpmyadmin was loading blank.  I could see the posted error in nginx error log.

I have managed to solve it by installing php8.1-fpm in the server and configured phpmyadmin.conf to work using php8.1-fpm.